# DLL GetProcAddress Problem - Another Run-Time Check Failure

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Well, i am having some issues with an error that i don't understand.

These are the two related files:

Inside **DLLExporter**:

```
#ifdef LOGGER_EXPORTS
    #define LOGGER_API __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall
#else
    #define LOGGER_API __declspec(dllimport) __stdcall
#endif

typedef long (CALLBACK *LPFNTIMER)( void );

// Exported Functions
bool LOGGER_API Initialize( std::string filename, bool ShowConsole = true );
bool LOGGER_API Release( void );
bool LOGGER_API SetTimer( LPFNTIMER );

bool LOGGER_API Initialize(std::string filename, bool ShowConsole)
{
    [...]
}

bool LOGGER_API Release()
{
    [...]
}

bool LOGGER_API SetTimer(LPFNTIMER fn)
{
    [...]
}
```

inside **DLLExporter.def**

```
LIBRARY DLLExporter.dll
EXPORTS
    Initialize
    Release
    SetTimer
```

inside **DLLImporter**:

```
typedef long (__stdcall *LPFNTIMER)( void );

typedef bool (__stdcall *LPFNINITIALIZER)( string, bool );
typedef bool (__stdcall *LPFNTIMERSETUP)( LPFNTIMER );
typedef bool (__stdcall *LPFNRELEASER)( void );

[...]


long __stdcall TimerFunc()
{
    return 0;
}

[...]

if (g_DLLExporter == NULL)
    return false;

LogInit = (LPFNINITIALIZER)GetProcAddress(g_DLLExporter, "Initialize");
LogRelease = (LPFNRELEASER)GetProcAddress(g_DLLExporter, "Release");
LogTimer = (LPFNTIMERSETUP)GetProcAddress(g_DLLExporter, "SetTimer");

if ( LogInit == NULL || LogRelease == NULL || LogTimer == NULL)
    return false;

if (!LogInit("test.log", true))
    return false;

if (!LogRelease())
    return false;

if (!LogTimer(TimerFunc))
    return false;
```

This code runs all the way through to the LogTimer call which fails, with the Run-Time Check Failure #0 message.

> Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value
>   of ESP was not properly saved across a
>   function call.  This is usually a
>   result of calling a function declared
>   with one calling convention with a
>   function pointer declared with a
>   different calling convention.

I have already noted the __stdcall issues reported elsewhere, but as you can see above i have that included, and i even forced the __stdcall calling convention in the project properties (MSVS 2010). Any thoughts as to why i would get the error only on the timer function and not on the init or release functions?

Comment: This is a win32 app.

DLLExporter creates DLLExporter.dll
DLLImporter creates DLLImporter.exe which imports DLLExporter.dll at run time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just thinking, perhaps if you call LogTimer() before LogRelease()?

And what about passing the proper parameters to Initialize and SetTimer?

Comment: I have done that, with no change to the resulting changes. When i change it the LogTimer is still screwed up and generates the same error, while LogRelease still works properly.

Comment: The following links are SO links that relate to the same problem, directing me to think that it has to do with the __stdcall in the function naming and calling, but i don't think that is entirely the case here since i have explicitly changed everything over to use __stdcall, as well as implicitly through the project settings.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696306/run-time-check-failure-0-loading-queryfullprocessimagename-from-kernel32-dll
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520441/run-time-check-failure-0-why-am-i-getting-this-and-what-does-it-mean
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465207/run-time-check-failure-0-the-value-of-esp-was-not-properly-saved-across-a-fun
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433950/c-wrapper-of-c-dll-run-time-check-failure-0-the-value-of-esp-was-not-prop

Answer (score 0):

Well,

Not entirely sure why, but compiling in release worked fine. I changed the name of the function and it now works fine in debug and release mode =)!

thank you all a bunch!